# Node-Red. Is it possible to install a node offline just with a copied node folder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I have a node folder which was in node_modules directory copied from another device. Is it possible to install this folder into node-red offline in a new device?

Comment: You are going to need to add a LOT more detail to your question

Comment: Also have you done any research around offline installing npm modules?

Answer (score 0):

This is how nodes are developed, updated and tested. See the section

> Testing your node in Node-RED

in https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/first-node

Comment: First, this is a link only answer. Second, this won't help as if the machine is offline there is no way to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for install node-red in any of the system.
Here i have done this process in windows10 server os

Just copy your installed node-red directory and paste it to same directory in other system(without internet enable system).

Step 1:
First copy node.js installer in your (internet disable system) and installed it.

Step 2:
After successful installation of node.js with npm copy npm folder from below given directory

C:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\npm

Step 3:
Paste this folder in same directory in non-internet system(may be path different).

And Now setup completed

Open your CMD and type happily node-red and Boooooooom.

https://discourse.nodered.org/u/parth_thaker/activity